# Winforms data-binding: Period-delimited navigation path as DataMember causes exception. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, path, datamember

I keep having problems with Winforms data-binding, more specifically, whenever I specify a period-separated property path to be used as `DataMember`. For example:

```
public partial class SomeForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
{
    public SomeForm(Book bookToBeDisplayed)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        authorLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text", bookToBeDisplayed, "Author.Name");  
                                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                          //    I cannot get this to work.
    }
}


public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Person Author { … }
    …
}

public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { … }
    …
}
```

The line where I'm adding a binding between `authorLabel.Text` and `bookToBeDisplayed.Author.Name`  throws the following exception:

> *ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the property or column Name on the DataSource.*

The "Remarks" section of the [MSDN page about `System.Windows.Forms.Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.aspx) explains that period-separated navigation paths can be used as `DataMember`:

> *You can also use a period-delimited navigation path when you bind to an object whose properties return references to other objects (such as a class with properties that return other class objects).*

What do I have to do to make the above example work?

- I've already made sure that the `Book` instance passed to `SomeForm`'s constructor is properly initialized, and that there are no `null` references.
- I also don't want to resort to `DataSets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Apparently, the `DataSource` must not be a single object, but a collection:

```
authorLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text",
                             new Book[] { bookToBeDisplayed },  // <--
                             "Author.Name");
```

The section "Types of Data Binding" of [the MSDN page "Data Binding and Windows Forms"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx) mentions that there are two types of data bindings: "simple" and "complex" ones. The latter binding type is also called "list-based binding". It seems that navigation paths are only supported with the latter binding type.

**P.S.:** MSDN also recommends using [`BindingList<T>`](http://channel9.msdn.com/), though that's probably not necessary here.

Comment: No they are supported elsewhere too.. There's some very hideous bug out there, or some underdocumented set of cases.. On my personal computer I can freely bind to `aBook,"Author.Name"` and everything works properly, but the very same code, not a letter changed, when run on another computer throws ArgumentException about 'Name' property not being found. That's just insane..

Comment: It's not necessarily a "bug" when they say that for such data binding, you need to use list-based / complex data binding, but you're using simple data binding anyway. It *would* be a bug if their officially recommended & documented method didn't work correctly, or unreliably.

Comment: Thanks:) I fully understand that. Let me be more precise, don't take it as question directed to you. I write this because you seem to have seen this rare issue, and I wanted to let you know about it as a "curiosity" rather an issue. I claimed that there is a bug, because the WForms framework seems somewhat incoherent. I have 3 different machines, all of them have full packages .Net2.0, .Net3.0 and .Net4.0 installed. Fresh checkout from the same revision from SVN, rebuilt from scratch on each machine separately, no changes to source made. Code is simple:small POCO that implements INotifyPropChg

Comment: That POCO is called 'Model'. It has a property 'Product' (POCO, INPC, too) that has property "Name" (string). Now, the binding is plain simple: `textBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", Model, "Product.Name"));`. This code works perfectly on machine #1, but crashes with argument-exception on machines #2 and #3. This behaviour I call a bug :) I find it strange that the same binding either works, or not, without code changes. I'd understand if it never worked at machine #1. But if it works there, then it seems it is supported without complexizing it with a collection-wrapper.

Comment: Damn, were it not supported in suc obvious way that even proper exception 'cannot bind to property' is raised, then IMHO, it should never work! Either way, there is some bug, although I truly do not know what it is (supported or not?), nor where it is..

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
authorLabel.DataBindings.Add("Text",bookToBeDisplayed.Author,"Name");
```

Comment: When `bookToBeDisplayed`'s `Author` property is changed to a new `Author` object, the label is still bound to the old author if you bind it the way you've shown.